# Missing methods in Forge ACC API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

Looking at the forge API documentation for ACC, I see that they don't support forward Compatibility from BIM360 for many key account admin methods, specifically:  POST projects, POST projects/:project_id/users/import (v2).

Yet I also don't see new methods for those operations (create a new project, add users to a project).

Am I missing something or is there no public API for those operations in ACC, and if not when do you think a public API for those operations will be available?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently **POST projects**, **POST projects/:project_id/users/import (v2)** are not supported for ACC.

Though you can take a look at [Autodesk Construction Cloud API updates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6IwvSek4rA&list=PLuFh5NgXkweOuXFOjgthn3sXZN02F7NsK&index=2) and see what's in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The video you linked did say those APIs are in the pipeline but directed for a different video for roadmap, the other video said that the plan for those APIs was q4 of 2021, I am guessing this didn't happen but I will appreciate if I can get a new estimation for timeline for those APIs.

Thank you,